# How can I append only 3 html elements to a .col-3 div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got the function addProducts I made in js, which is to get details from a product's object.

```
function addProducts(product) {
let body = '';
body += "<div class='card' style='width:10rem;'";
body += "<img class='card-img-top' " + "src=" + product.img + " alt='card image'>";
body += "<div class='card-body'>";
body += "<h5 class='card-title'>" + product.name + "</h5>";
body += "<p class='card-text'>" + product.description + "</p>";
body += "<a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>" + "معرفة المزيد" + "</a>";

return body;

}
```

however, this is comes out with a .card container that details only one product. How could I add only 3 products just like this one , but in a .col-3 div ?

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
//Product 1
//Product 2
//Product 3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
//Product 1
//Product 2
//Product 3
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
//Product 1
//Product 2
//Product 3
                        </div>
            </div>
```

I add the products to appear in my container with the id of #products-list, with a for loop that's triggered on the event of 'nodeSelect'

```
let $productsList = $('#products-list');

onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
    var products = '';


    for (let i = 0; i < data.products.length; i++) {
        products += addProducts(data.products[i]);
    }


    $productsList.html(products);
    $productsList.show();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It would be best to also include an example of the`product` object.

Comment: Should I ask a new question with better details ?

Comment: @EsamOlwan You can update/edit this one.

Comment: Once you click the update/edit button, you can place your HTML/CSS and/or JS in a snippit that will parse the code, this allows you to provide an outcome of the current code your having issue with. The add snippit button will look like this: `<>`. Furthermore, it allow the community a centralized snippit of code that can be copied directly into their answer for a much easier way of debugging your issue and will help you potentially get a quicker and more favorable answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```
function addProducts(product) {
  // Create Card
  var card = $("<div>", {
    class: "card"
  }).css({
    width: "10rem"
  });
  $("<img>", {
    class: "card-img-top",
    src: product.img,
    alt: "Card Image"
  }).appendTo(card);
  var body = $("<div>", {
    class: "card-body"
  }).appendTo(card);
  $("<h5>", {
    class: "card-title"
  }).html(product.name).appendTo(body);
  $("<p>", {
    class: "card-text"
  }).html(product.description).appendTo(body);
  $("<a>", {
    href: "#",
    class: "btn btn-primary"
  }).html("معرفة المزيد").appendTo(body);
  // Return jQuery Object of populated Card
  return card;
}
// Define List as jQuery Object
var $productsList = $('#products-list');

// Event Action
onNodeSelected: function(event, data) {
  var products;
  // Clear current Product List
  $productsList.html("");
  // Iterate Object Data
  $.each(data.products, function(i, el)) {
    // i for the Index number and el for the object elements
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
      // use Modulus operator to wrap 3 items
      $("<div>", {
        class: "col-sm"
      }).appendTo($productList);
    }
    $(".col-sm:last", $productList).append(addProduct(el));
  }
  $productsList.show();
}
```

Without a proper example, I could not test the code. You will have to test it on your own.

See more on Modulus Operator: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arithmetic.asp